# String index out of bounds in Jjava

Tags: java, string, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

What is the best way to check if a string index is in bounds? Let's say we are checking a String for index `i-1` or `i+1`  because you cannot say != null.

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) 
{
    if (string.charAt(i+1) == '#' && string.charAt(i - 1) != '1') 
    {    
    }
}
```

Should you just check the length of the string and see if it is within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.charAt(i+1) == '#'
```

Yes, I think you need to make sure `i+1` is not greater than String length.

Example:

```
if( (i+1) < string.length() && (i-1) >= 0 && (yourcode))
   { 
   }
```

Comment: I had tried it and it was giving me an index error. Would this be right. if ((i+1) <= string.length() && (i-1) >= (string.length() -1) && myCode)

Comment: @Paul, I think you need to add negative check also as jontro commente, otherwise for first index, i-1 would be -1.

Comment: ok thanks that is what I have already, I must be getting the error elsewhere. Ah I see I had a >= instead of a >

Comment: @Paul: Glad you found out. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check the length of the string?

```
if(myString.length() - 1 > i)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always modified the length (and/or start) of the loop in these cases... these are all good answers - there's no one way to do it, but this is how I would do it:

```
for (int i = 1; i < string.length() - 1; i++) 
{
    if (string.charAt(i+1) == '#' && (i != 1 || string.charAt(i - 1) != '1'))
    {    
    }
}
```

EDIT: After considering all of the situations that this code entails, I wouldn't necessarily do this in this manner, but find a cleaner way to express exactly what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to change your `for` loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < string.length() - 1; i++) 
{
    if (string.charAt(i+1) == '#' && string.charAt(i - 1) != '1') 
    {    
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

`string.charAt(i - 1)` implies that you might read position `i-1` of the string. Since 0 is the lowest valid value you can start the iteration with `i = 1`

`string.charAt(i + 1)` implies that you might read position `i+1` of the string. Since `string.length() - 1` is the highest valid value you need to end your iteration at `i == string.length() - 2`. Since the for-loop checks the condition before entering the loop using `i < string.length() - 1` will be just right.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with this code.

```
for (int i = 1; string!= null && string.length() >= 3 && i < string.length() - 1; i++) 
//it solve the case of String == null and string too short
//it optimize the max number of cycles
{
    if (string.charAt(i+1) == '#' && string.charAt(i - 1) != '1') 
    {    
    }
}
```